# How to tag a facebook page in FBSDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

While using the FBSDK for iOS, I am trying to attach/tag a relevant facebook page. Any pointers to their docs? I looked up some info on message_tags parameter but not sure how to use it.

```
let shareParams = ["message":"Check out this page @PAGE_NAME"]
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: shareParams, HTTPMethod: "POST")
fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection :FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result, error) -> Void in

  if let responseError = error {
    if responseError.domain == FacebookSharerErrorDomain.FacebookAPIError.rawValue {
      self.handleFacebookAPIError(responseError)
    } else {
      Error("Unable to share")
    }
  } else {
    Success("Shared to Facebook")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#mentions) is what you looking for (if anchor didn't work refresh page. or search "Mentioning Friends or Pages" section).

Also look at [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/taggable_friends) endpoint.